# Bind workflow properties to list items in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, workflow

I have created a workflow in Visual Studio 2010 which contains a custom action that creates a subsite. I enter the values for URL and SiteName in the property window of Visual Studio. So far it is OK, but rather than hard coding these properties, I would like to bind them with items of a list.

For your info, the workflow is reusable. So, it is not attached to a sharepoint list.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of workflow action is that your values can be set during the run time ( either workflow itself based on some parameter or through SharePoint designer )

If you want to set these values during runtime, you need to pass these values to your custom action.

I am missing something?